# ngClass and print media query not working together

Tags: css, angular, media-queries, ng-class

I am making an angular component to make a bunch of qr codes and print them. I have a component just for the qr code and want to make it possible to delete a qr code from the list and undo-delete a previously deleted code. I Before adding the undo-delete functionality, everything was working well because I was just removing that particular component from the list. However, now I don't want to completely remove it, I just want to fade it out until print time. I am using ngClass on my div and the "deleted" class does work. Anything that has class noPrint just gets display:none, however when I try to use ngClass to dynamically give a code noPrint, it doesn't set display: none on that particular code.

My qr-code html: The issue is in the first div tag at the top. I have tried adding single quotes on the class names to see if that works as well.

```
<div
  fxLayout="column"
  class="qrobj"
  [ngClass]="{
    deleted: !this.shouldExist,
    noPrint: !this.shouldExist
  }"
>
  <button *ngIf="this.shouldExist" class="noPrint" mat-icon-button>
    <mat-icon
      matTooltip="Delete this Person?"
      matTooltipPosition="after"
      color="warn"
      (click)="sendDelete()"
      >block</mat-icon
    >
  </button>
  <button *ngIf="!this.shouldExist" class="noPrint" mat-icon-button>
    <mat-icon
      matTooltip="Undo Delete?"
      matTooltipPosition="after"
      color="primary"
      (click)="undoDelete()"
      >undo
    </mat-icon>
  </button>
  <div fxLayout="row" class="text">
    <p>{{ person.Name }}</p>
    <p>{{ person.Name }}</p>
  </div>
  <div fxLayout="row" class="images">
    <img [src]="this.qrlink" (error)="getDefaultUrl()" />
    <img [src]="this.piclink" (error)="getDefaultUrl()" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the part of my css that matters:

```
.deleted {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

@media print {
  .noPrint {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

This is what it looks like 
before I delete a Code

[image]

This is what it looks like 
after I delete a Code:
[image]

This is what shows up in the print preview:
[image]

Comment: Did you fix this?

Comment: not yet. I've been looking periodically, but because it's not the most important thing, I haven't looked much into it.